# Retail analytics dataset for use in a paid course

Tags: uses-of-open-data

I'm designing an online, paid course in retail analytics, and I'm looking for a dataset that I can use for that course.  If I find datasets that are 'open data' then am I allowed to use those datasets within a paid course?  Are there any good sites for finding such datasets with retail or marketing data?

Comment: *If I find datasets that are 'open data' then am I allowed to use those datasets within a paid course?* Not necessarily (and often not). Look at the conditions for use.